# twisted proxy randomly redirects

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy, twisted, reverse-proxy

I have a very simple reverse-proxy script in twisted:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web import proxy, server
from twisted.python import log
from twisted.names import client

site = server.Site(proxy.ReverseProxyResource('www.example.com', 80, ''.encode("utf-8")))
reactor.listenTCP(80, site)
reactor.run()
```

But sometimes when I connect to my server, It redirects to random website like `test0.com` and sometimes websites that claim I have a virus. I wondering if there is a bug in Twisted? or if anybody has experienced this before?